# Show default item in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a ListBox show an initial value before I'm adding items into it (something like: "No files added"), but I'm getting the error " Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.".

I'm new to WPF and I'm not sure in which direction to go from here. I've looked at the INotifyPropertyChanged interace, but it seems like an overly complicated solution to a simple problem (or am I misunderstanding the use of INotifyPropertychanged?).

My XAML looks like this:

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             Name="DbListBox"
             Grid.Column="3"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Height="246"
             Margin="0,99,0,0"
             Grid.Row="1"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="211"
             SelectionMode="Single"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=selectedDB,Mode=TwoWay}" 
             AllowDrop="True"
             Drop="DbListBox_Drop">
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="ListBox.DataContext">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>Drag .db file here or add below</TextBlock>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ListBox>
```

In my code-behind I have this ObservableCollection `public ObservableCollection<string> DbCollection;` which I'm setting as the ListBox' ItemsSource which is where I'm getting the error, at the Items collection apparently has to be empty before I can assign something else to it:

```
        DbListBox.ItemsSource = DbCollection;
        this.DataContext = this;
```

`

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are adding `DataTrigger` into `ListBox.ItemsSource`.

Comment: I can see that now. That's not gonna work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using some trigger (I can see the trigger you used, but it's not properly added) listening to `Items.Count` or `ItemsSource.Count` or `ItemsSource.IsEmpty` or `HasItems` property and set the `Template` to some `TextBlock` (with some Text showing the message you want) so that it's centered (both horizontally and vertically) at the ListBox.

```
<ListBox.Style>
   <Style TargetType="ListBox">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                     <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                       <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                Foreground="Gray" FontSize="30"
                                Text="No files added"/>
                     </Border>
                  </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</ListBox.Style>
```

Changing the `Template` is something overkill in some cases which may require you to add more code. We can also set the `Background` to some `VisualBrush` showing some text captured from a TextBlock like this:

```
<ListBox.Style>
  <Style TargetType="ListBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
         <Setter Property="Background">
           <Setter.Value>                 
              <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                  <TextBlock Text="No files added" FontSize="30" 
                             Foreground="Gray"/>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
              </VisualBrush>
           </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</ListBox.Style>
```

Comment: @Left4Cookies you're welcome, see my update for another neater code. I think setting the Background is better than setting the Template.

Comment: So we're just setting the background of the ListBox instead of adding a controltemplate on top of it?

Comment: @Left4Cookies something like that, but setting the `ControlTemplate` will replace the ListBox completely (not placed on top of the ListBox). That's why sometimes you may need more code, such as when you set some `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` for the ListBox, you have to bind the `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` of the inner `Border` to the ListBox's (I do the similar thing with `Background` as you can see in the first code: `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"`).